# MySQL tables name

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have a question on MySQL.

In a server Ubuntu (system version: 14.04) I have installed Mysql 5.5.37 (LAMP distribution). After an export from a server Windows I have installed a database with the names of the tables in upper case format.

In this first import the upper case format is preserved.

After some week I have made a new export from the same Windows server and I have installed the same database but in another server Ubuntu (system version: 14.04, version of MySQL: 5.5.35, LAMP distribution) but in this case the upper case format of the name of the tables has not been maintained.

I would like to know why MySQL in the new server Ubuntu have this behavior.

Old server:
Ubuntu 14.04
MySQL: 5.5.37

New server:
Ubuntu: 14.04
MySQL: 5.5.35

Thanks in advance at all.

Comment: how can you install LAMP on a Linux server ???

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names. This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

However, you can tweak this behavior by setting `lower_case_table_names` flag. From [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names),

- If `lower_case_table_names` is set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case sensitive.
- If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive.
- If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase. This option also applies to database names and table aliases.

I suggest you compare this flag between 2 of your imports.

Comment: Hi hashbrown. Thanks for the reply.
I'll try to use your suggestion.

Comment: @Lorenzo - sure, if the suggestion helps, consider accepting the answer